# AWS AL2 - Elastic beanstalk - how can I proper install Postgres 15?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, yum

I have an Elastic Beanstalk enviroment with AL2 system (latest available) and until today, I used `amazon-linux-extras` to install PG 14 with this command:

`sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql14`

Now I want to update to postgresql15 but seems that `amazon-linux-extras` is not providing it for AL2 (seems providing it for AL2023, for AL2 only PG 11, 12, 13, 14) . Or, I can't find the way to enable it.

So I'm here to ask if someone knows a way to properly install postgresql15 on AL2 enviroment.

Thanks a lot for all the info and the help

EDIT:

To give more context, I need this package to run PG CLI commands on my instance, not to have a DB on that.
My instance is a worker that perform various jobs and one of these is to create a dump of an existing RDS instance, that's why I need the package.